# SignalR Javascript Client: Cannot Start Connection

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

My connection does not start. 
This code worked in 1.x but in version 2 is not working.

SignalR seems to be trying to connect but without success. 
The hub method is never called.

Attached sending an image with SignalR debug.

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    var options = { transport: ['webSockets', 'longPolling'] };

    $(function() {
        var userHub = $.connection.userHub;

        //Iniciar connecção
        window.hubReady = $.connection.hub.start(options);

        window.hubReady.done(function () {
            userHub.server.ini();
        });

        userHub.client.iniDone = function (connectionId) {
            console.log(connectionId);
        };

        $.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function() {
            console.log('slow connection...');
        });

        window.hubReady.fail(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

        $.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.connection.hub.start();
            }, 2000);
        });

    });

</script>
```

**Hub:**

```
[HubName("userHub")]
public class UserHub : Hub
{
    public void Ini()
    {
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).iniDone(string.Format("Conectado com o id: {0}", Context.ConnectionId));
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {

        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        var email = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Context.User.Identity.Name) ? Context.Headers["email"] : Context.User.Identity.Name;


        if (email != null && connectionId != null)
            UserData.GetInstance(email).ConnectionsIds.Add(connectionId);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {

        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        var email = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Context.User.Identity.Name) ? Context.Headers["email"] : Context.User.Identity.Name;


        if (email != null && connectionId != null)
            UserData.GetInstance(email).ConnectionsIds.Remove(connectionId);

        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }
}
```

**Debug:**

[SignalR Debug Image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13732882/debug.png)

**EDIT:**

I found the problem! The GetInstance method of my Singleton has problems.

```
public static UserData GetInstance(string username)
{
    if (_sharedUsers == null) 
        lock (_lockCreate) 
                _sharedUsers = new Dictionary<string, UserData>(); 

    if (!_sharedUsers.ContainsKey(username)) 
        lock (_lockAdd) 
            _sharedUsers.Add(username, new UserData(username)); 

    return _sharedUsers[username];
}
```

the method stops always here: lock (_lockAdd)

I want to save all user connectionsIds Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: So in the Hub on the server, you're not seeing `OnConnected` getting called? Or is it just `Ini` not getting called?

Comment: The debug image you list also shows that all attempts to connect to the server timeout. Can you confirm the server at `http://localhost:38219` is running?

Comment: OnConnected and OnDisconnected are called. Ini() is not called

Comment: yes, it is running on IIS Express

Comment: I put a console.log() inside the function done(), and this is never called

Comment: So when debugging the server, can you see that the `OnConnected` complete successfully? Just trying to rule out any server errors.

Comment: return base.OnConnected(); -> This line is not executed

So I commented the following line:
UserData.GetInstance(email).ConnectionsIds.Add(connectionId);

So i see that the OnConnected complete successfully.

SignalR show:
SignalR: EventSource connected.
 SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332 and a connection lost timeout of 20000.
SignalR: Keep alive has been missed, connection may be dead/slow.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the client method subscription to be before you connect. If it's not registered by the time the connection is started, then it will not be callable from the server.

So change it to the following:

```
$(function() {
    var userHub = $.connection.userHub;

    //Register Client handlers first
    userHub.client.iniDone = function (connectionId) {
        console.log(connectionId);
    };

    //Now you can connect.
    window.hubReady = $.connection.hub.start(options);

    window.hubReady.done(function () {
        userHub.server.ini();
    });

    $.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function() {
        console.log('slow connection...');
    });

    window.hubReady.fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    $.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }, 2000);
    });

});
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment around a server error in the `OnConnected` method, it seems like you may have a two problems then. Isolate the connection tracking part out (just comment it out) to get the full round-trip going between client and server. Then add back the connection tracking which is possibly a DB connection error - check the server logs.

**Edit**

In terms of storing the user connections, you've a few options.

*Use `ConcurrentDictionary`:*

One of the simplest is storing in a static `ConcurrentDictionary`, similar to what you have. Try to avoid the use of so many locks - using a `ConcurrentDictionary` means you'll actually end up with none.

e.g.

```
    public class UserData
    {
        public UserData(string username)
        {
            UserName = username;
            ConnectionIds = new HashSet<string>();
        }

        public string UserName { get; private set; }
        public HashSet<string> ConnectionIds { get; private set; } 
    }

    public static class ConnectionStore
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserData> _userData = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserData>();

        public static void Join(string username, string connectionId)
        {
            _userData.AddOrUpdate(username, 
                u => new UserData(u),                   /* Lambda to call when it's an Add */
                (u, ud) => {                            /* Lambda to call when it's an Update */
                    ud.ConnectionIds.Add(connectionId);
                    return ud;
            });
        }
    }
```

See MSDN for more info: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

*Use a database:*

The other option is to store in a database (using Entity Framework) which has the added benefit of tracking user data across server recycles.

Have a look at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections which shows all these options a couple of others.

Comment: Matt i found the problem! The GetInstance method of my Singleton has problems.

Comment: You'll still have problems calling the client-side from the server, unless you reorder as above.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem for so long, so gave up the whole signalR at some point, but had to pick it up again for our project:

I have written an answer which might lead you and others on the right track (step by step)...In the answer I am using PersistentConnection rather than Hub, but the principle should be the same:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25304790/3940626